# Implementing Auto Complete with Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, autocomplete

I am trying to implement an auto-complete search with a list of people. I would like the list to shrink as the user types in the name they are looking for.

I found a good resource at from the guys at Embercasts, but unfortunately they never finished part 2.

Video:

http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/building-an-autocomplete-widget-part-1

Source Code:

https://github.com/embercasts/building-an-autocomplete-widget

I don't understand the following:

- How do I indicate what model I want the auto complete to filter? The demo code uses an array, but I can't figure out how to have it use my model and filter by nameFirst and nameLast name.

Data:

```
App.Swimmer = DS.Model.extend({
    nameFirst: DS.attr(),
    nameLast: DS.attr(),
    level: DS.attr(),
    birthdate: DS.attr(),
    gender: DS.attr(),
    note:DS.attr(),
    lesson: DS.belongsTo('lesson', {async: true}),
    family:DS.belongsTo('family',{async: true})
});
```

A quick demo of how to implement this auto complete using a model and fixture data would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The caveat here is that the FixtureAdapter does not support query logic.  Here's an untested (!) solution that should work with the RESTAdapter...

#### Javascript:

```
App.SwimmerController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    filterFirst: null,
    filterLast: null,
    filteredMatches: function() {
        return this.store.find('swimmer', {
            nameFirst: this.get('filterFirst'),
            nameLast: this.get('filterLast')
        });
    }.property('filterFirst', 'filterLast')
});
```

#### Template:

```
<div>
    <em>First:</em>{{input value=filterFirst}} <em>Last:</em>{{input value=filterLast}}
</div>
<ul>
    {{#each result in filteredMatches}}
        <li>{{result.nameFirst}} {{result.nameLast}}</li>
    {{else}}
        <em>No matches found!</em>
    {{/each}}
<ul/>
```